# Why use readonly IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, ienumerable, immutability, readonly, mutability

Why would you declare an `IEnumerable<T>` `readonly`?

From the this [article on async & await](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=869) we have the following code.

```
class OrderHandler
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<Order> _orders;

    public OrderHandler()
    {
        // Set orders.
    }
    public IEnumerable<Order> GetAllOrders()
    {
        return _orders;
    }
}
```

`IEnumerable<T>` is immutable. How is this different from the `readonly` keyword?

Comment: `IEnumerable<T>` isn't itself immutable, the list it iterates can change between iterations. Unless it's running over an `IImmutableList<T>`, basically it depends on the underlying list.

Comment: `IEnumerable<T>` is what C++ would call `const` - it doesn't give you any operations to modify the object, but it cannot stop the object from being modified via other interfaces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `readonly` keyword here applies to the field `_orders`. It simply means that the field can not be assigned a different value during the lifetime of the object. For example, this is not possible:

```
class OrderHandler
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<Order> _orders;

    public OrderHandler()
    {
        // Set orders.
    }

    void SomeMethod()
    {
        _orders = new Order[0];
    }
}
```

You will receive this compiler error:

> A `readonly` field cannot be assigned to (except in a constructor or a variable initializer)

This **does not** make the collection read-only. For example, you could still do this:

```
class OrderHandler
{
    public readonly IEnumerable<Order> Orders;

    public OrderHandler()
    {
        Orders = new List<Order>();
    }
}

((List<Order>)OrderHandler.Orders).Add(new Order());
```

Which would probably violate the thread-safety of the class. See [*Tigran*'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17649774/1715579) for information on immutable collections.

**Further Reading**

- [readonly (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Would ReadOnlyCollection<T> achieve the same? the readonly in this case would be redundant?

Comment: @SamLeach No. The two are very different. The `readonly` applies to the field, not to the semantics of the type.

Comment: @SamLeach for example, if you initialise a `readonly` property in the constructor, it can **never** be null and no consumers of the class can ever assign null to the list.  As far as expected behaviours of lists go, this is very healthy, as a list should be empty or have items, but never null.

Comment: As an after thought, if the type is a mutable reference type, it can still be modified?

Comment: @SamLeach Yes, see my updated answer. I've provided an example of how it can be modified even if you only expose an immutable interface *and* mark the field as `readonly`. The only thing that `readonly` actually makes read only, is the field.

Answer (score 4):

In addition would add that event if it defines `_orders` as immutable, this makes immutable only reference itself, *but not the content of that collection.* I still can change object inside that enumeration.

For this reason beginning from the C# 5.0, we will get :

[Immutable Collections in .NET Framework](http://www.techbubbles.com/c/immutable-collections-in-net-framework/)

Quoting article:

> Immutable Collections are collections which guarantees that they never
>   change their content and completely thread safe

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, the `readonly` qualifier makes the *reference* stored in a class-object's class-type field immutable once the constructor of that object has finished, but has no such effect on any object to which the reference may refer.  There is no plausible means by which the qualifier could affect in that way the object to which the reference refers, since other copies of the reference could exist stored in fields without such a qualifier.

That does not, however, imply that the `readonly` keyword cannot usefully be applied to mutable objects.  Suppose one had a class `Foo` with a field `stuff` that held an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int,string>>`, and one wanted it to expose a property `Keys` of a type which implements `IEnumerable<int>` containing the key-part of each item in `stuff`.  If `stuff` is held a read-only field, then a wrapper object returned by `Keys` could hold a reference to `stuff` and have a "live view" of any changes to the collection.  If, however, `stuff` were not a read-only field, then the wrapper object would have to have a reference to the `Foo` upon which the `Keys` property was called if it wanted to ensure that it would always behave as a live view.